# Warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++, c

I have a function like :

```
char * s;
{
    char * i = s, * t;

    for(t = s;*t != NULL;t++)
        if (*t == '/') i = t+1;

    return i;
}
```

The warning I get is comparison between pointer and integer. How can U resolve it?

Comment: Instead of `*t != NULL` you should have `*t != '\0'`.

Comment: must say, I've never seen a function declared like that. Is that c syntax?

Comment: @Smac89 It's not a function declaration, but legal C syntax, the `{}` create a block.

Comment: its not a function. That was just a block of code. Sorry for mentioning FUNCTION.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop treating `NULL` as a character, it's supposed to be a pointer-type constant.

Your loop header should be:

```
for(t = s; *t != '\0'; ++t)
```

This is the "overly explicit" way of writing it, some C programmers aiming for maximum terseness will just say:

```
for(t = s; *t; ++t)
```

Since a comparison to `'\0'` is the same as a comparison to 0, which is implicit in just evaluating the expression. However, I think the `!= '\0'` helps in reading since it makes it clear what's going on, we're looking for the string terminator `'\0'`. The comparison should be trivially optimized out by any sane compiler.